# Gradle dependency based on both build type and flavor

Tags: android, gradle

I have several build types: `debug`, `release`.
I also have two flavors `pub` and `dev`.

`pub` flavored application depends on a `pub` library, the similar goes for `dev` flavor.
Now I'd like the `debug` build type app depend on `debug` build of the library. The following does not work:

```
pubReleaseCompile project(path: ':common', configuration: "pubRelease")
devReleaseCompile project(path: ':common', configuration: "devRelease")
pubDebugCompile project(path: ':common', configuration: "pubDebug")
devDebugCompile project(path: ':common', configuration: "devDebug")
```

Note: The library is set up to compile all variants.

Is there a way to specify conditional project dependency based on both flavor and build type?

**EDIT:** To avoid confusion here follow relevant `build.gradle` files from the project that I'm currently using.

**project/common/build.gradle** (the library)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.hugo' // annotation-based code generated logs only in debug build

android {
  defaultPublishConfig "pubRelease"
  publishNonDefault true // four variants of the library are built

  buildTypes {
    debug {}
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
  }
  productFlavors {
    pub {
      // custom build config fields
    }
    dev {
      // custom build config fields
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  // ...
}
```

**project/parent/build.gradle** (one of the app modules using the library)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.hugo'

android {
  // ...

  signingConfigs {
    release {
      // ...
    }
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
      signingConfig signingConfigs.release
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
      shrinkResources true
      minifyEnabled true
    }
    debug {
      versionNameSuffix '-debug'
    }
  }
  productFlavors {
    pub {
      // custom res values
    }
    dev {
      // custom res values
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  // ...
  pubCompile project(path: ':common', configuration: "pubRelease")
  devCompile project(path: ':common', configuration: "devRelease")
}
```

Comment: What error does it say? Is that `Could not find method pubReleaseCompile () for arguments xxx`?

Comment: `Gradle DSL method not found: 'pubReleaseCompile()'`.

Comment: Ever find out how to do this?

Comment: Sadly no, but currently I'd use it only for [Hugo](https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo) so it's not critical. If you'd like I'll post a bounty.

Comment: I would like that very much.

Comment: If there is a way to get a string representation of the current buildtype then that could be useful.

Comment: **For more detailed Q/A see:** [Multi flavor app based on multi flavor library in Android Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860659/multi-flavor-app-based-on-multi-flavor-library-in-android-gradle)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

#### Android Plugin for Gradle 3.x.x

Build plugin 3.x.x uses variant-aware dependency resolution so `devDebug` variant of an app module will automatically use `devDebug` variant of its library module dependency. To answer the question, this would be enough:

```
implementation project(':common')
```

Read more here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#variant_aware

#### Original answer

I was able to find a solution here: https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020/blob/master/build.gradle

More on why my original code does not suffice is available here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=162285

Working solution:

```
configurations {
  pubDebugCompile
  devDebugCompile
  pubReleaseCompile
  devReleaseCompile
}

dependencies {
  pubReleaseCompile project(path: ':common', configuration: "pubRelease")
  devReleaseCompile project(path: ':common', configuration: "devRelease")
  pubDebugCompile project(path: ':common', configuration: "pubDebug")
  devDebugCompile project(path: ':common', configuration: "devDebug")
}
```

Comment: There may be no need in manual configuration in future: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=162285

Comment: I have a related question here but cannot resolve yet.
I have tried what you have suggested and still no luck.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36156596/gradle-subproject-external-library-dependency-based-on-main-project-module-fla

Comment: @Wayne You have to define build types and flavours and then configurations with this name pattern: "<flavour><BuildType>Compile". You can't just define random configurations.

Comment: @Eugen Perchance I am just omitting the <BuildType> ... I am going to try that.
thanks for the help.

Are you aware of a git project that has an example?

Comment: @Wayne If you don't define build types there are implicitly two: `debug` and `release`. You have to define product flavors in your library as well. Say you define `fOne` and `fTwo`, then you can use `fOneCompile` and `fTwoCompile` in your library's dependencies. Then you have to tell the compiler you want all library configurations built (all combinations of flavour and build type). And then your app module can depend on `fOneRelease` etc. **The whole example is laid out for you in the question, just read it carefully.**

Comment: 3.0.0 link seems broken as of today. This should be the new one: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#variant_aware

Answer (score 5):

First define the various build types:

```
buildTypes {
    pubRelease {
        //config
    }
    devRelease {
        //config
    }
}
```

Create a task that will be executed only for a specific buildType and flavor:

```
task pubReleaseTask << {
    //code
}

task devReleaseTask << {
    //code
}
```

You can add the dependency dynamically:

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'pubRelease') {
        task.dependsOn pubReleaseTask
    }
    if (task.name == 'devRelease') {
        task.dependsOn devReleaseTask 
    }
}
```

Comment: If I did `gradlew clean build` wouldn't this add all the dependencies at once?

Comment: Two questions: **1)** Re: UPDATE: But still if I'm doing a full build it's going to do all tasks, so the first flavor specific task will get it's own dependency and every consecutive flavor specific task will get it's own plus whatever has already been added. Is this correct or not? **2)** On which tasks should i hook the new ones?

Comment: @EugenPechanec - Please find the answer updated with more explanation.

Comment: So I added [this](http://pastebin.com/z4t8HiqV) at the end of my *app module* `build.gradle`. Won't compile, did not find library resources. Where did you come up with the 'pubRelease' and 'devRelease' task names? There are no such tasks in the project. (Thank you so much  for your patience.)

Comment: Also please note that the *build types* are `release` and `debug` and the *flavors* are `pub` and `dev`.

Comment: Error:(364, 0) Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':app:compile' after it has been included in dependency resolution.

Answer (score 3):

Follow up @dooplaye's example, assume you only want to compile leanback in one flavor, you could refer to below snippet:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def flavorString = ""
    def flavors = variant.productFlavors
    for (int i = 0; i < flavors.size(); i++) {
        flavorString += flavors[i].name;
    }

    if (flavorString.equalsIgnoreCase("pubdeb")) {
        dependencies {
            compile('com.android.support:leanback-v17:22.2.1')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this error: Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':app:compile' after it has been included in dependency resolution.

Comment: There already is (and was 4 years ago) a standard way of doing this: `dependencies { pubdebCompile('com.android.support:leanback-v17:22.2.1') }` The question requires that you already know how to declare dependencies based on flavor. I'm voting this down.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Multi-flavor variants](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors)
You shouldn't use buildTypes for this. 
But you can define multi-flavors:

```
flavorDimensions "first", "second"

productFlavors {
    pub {
        flavorDimension "first"
    }
    dev {
        flavorDimension "first"
    }
    deb {
        flavorDimension "second"
    }
    rel {
        flavorDimension "second"
    }
}
```

And then you can add dependencies to your libs like this

```
pubRelCompile project(path: ':common', configuration: "pubRel")
devRelCompile project(path: ':common', configuration: "devRel")
pubDebCompile project(path: ':common', configuration: "pubDeb")
devDebCompile project(path: ':common', configuration: "devDeb")
```

Comment: That would include `pubRelease` library in both `pubDebug` and `pubRelease` variant of app. This is what I'm using already. What I'm looking for is including `pubRelease` library in `pubRelease` app and `pubDebug` library in `pubDebug` app.

Comment: Re Edit: Can't do that. Would have to use buildTypes only and after that I'd have to maintain duplicate values for what-used-to-be-flavors. This is not an option.

Comment: This would generate twice as many APKs with next to no gain. Check out my solution and the associated sources.