# Gradle subproject external library dependency based on (main) project module flavours

Tags: android, gradle

I have two modules an **app** and a **library** and 
two external maven libraries that I use.

The external libraries have slight differences and are selected based on the build flavour together with the maven classifier.

Both the (subproject/module) and the (main module) use the same external library based on the flavour.

> My problem is I cannot control/select the subproject library when
>   compiling.

**Module App:**

```
apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
productFlavors {
fOne {}
fTwo {}
}
}

dependencies {   
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.1'

// selecting the library based on the flavour
fOneCompile(group: 'com.xyz', name: 'SDK', version: '1.0', ext: 'aar')
fTwoCompile(group: 'com.xyz', name: 'SDK', version: '1.0', classifier: 'qa', ext: 'aar')

 //<< the library also needs the com.xyz.SDK
 fOneCompile project(path: ':library', configuration: "fOneCompile") 
 fTwoCompile project(path: ':library', configuration: "fTwoCompile")


}
```

**Module library:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
....
}

repositories{    
  jcenter()
  flatDir{
      dirs 'libs'
   }
}

configurations {
    fOne
    fTwo 
}

dependencies {
    ??? what goes here, flavours are not available ??? 
    //the library also needs the com.xyz.SDK
    fOneCompile(group: 'com.xyz', name: 'SDK', version: '1.0', ext: 'aar')
    fTwoCompile(group: 'com.xyz', name: 'SDK', version: '1.0', classifier: 'qa', ext: 'aar')
}
```

Module **library** fails to compile because it can not find the SDK and I
need to include one based on the flavour being compiled.

Comment: " apply plugin: 'com.android.library' "    add this to B

Comment: my bad ,, that was not copied and is not the problem. I have updated the question.

Comment: main proj's  'settings gradle'  has "include ';projectB'  "

Comment: on cli from proj A  " ./gradlew --info --stacktrace :projectB:clean :projectB:assembleDebug  "

Comment: https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android/blob/master/build.gradle#L90 for the parent , https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android/blob/master/build.gradle#L59  for the lib

Comment: Thanks the links Robert, still stuck. I have updated my question code
to use the configurations that I pass in when building the subproject,
but it seems this is being ignored.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=52962    did u look at the bug mention in the link above?? sounds like similar issue which the sample git proj resolved with a workaround noted in the gradle files

Answer (score 1):

Use this config:

```
defaultConfig {
       publishNonDefault true
}

configurations {
    fOneDebugCompile
    fOneReleaseCompile
    fTwoDebugCompile
    fTwoReleaseCompile
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple, since there are duplicate dependencies and the
main project selects the appropriate dependency one can use the "provided" 
statement int the sub modules when dependencies are resolved.

In this case one can replace the "compile" statement in the dependencies
section with "provided" in the Module library(sub module):

**Module library:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
....
}

repositories{    
  jcenter()
  flatDir{
      dirs 'libs'
   }
}

dependencies {
    //the library also needs the com.xyz.SDK
    provided(group: 'com.xyz', name: 'SDK', version: '1.0', ext: 'aar')
}
```