# Gradle group module dependencies based on flavors

Tags: android, gradle

The problem that I have is that the regular

```
dependencies {
    compile project(path: ':moduleOne', configuration: "typeRelease")
}
```

is not enough for my app's purposes. I have quite a list of dependencies with different configurations (and flavors + build types) involved, and what I want to do now is to add some kind of a method to leverage those dependencies.

For example,

```
dependencies {
    flavorOneAnalyticsCompile project(path: ':moduleOne', configuration: "typeRelease")
    flavorOneFlurryCompile project(path: ':moduleOne', configuration: "typeRelease")
    flavorOneCrashlyticsCompile project(path: ':moduleOne', configuration: "typeRelease")
    flavorTwoAnalyticsCompile project(path: ':moduleOne', configuration: "typeStaging")
    flavorTwoLoggingCompile project(path: ':moduleOne', configuration: "typeStaging")
        }
```

Is it possible to say "I want all my build variants with `FlavorOne` to compile `moduleOne` with `typeRelease` configuration, and all build varians with `FlavorTwo` to compile `moduleOne` with `typeStaging` configuration"?

Does anybody know how to do it? Is this even possible? I have found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28137853/gradle-dependency-based-on-both-build-type-and-flavor) how to use flavor + build type dependencies, but it's quite ugly to have this big fat list of similarly-looking dependencies.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Well, since Gradle is Groovy, you have access to loops and arbitrary data structures, if that helps.

Comment: Any solution, i have same problem