# dependencies based on multiple productFlavors

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have 2 `buildTypes` and 5 `productFlavors` in my application.

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }

    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

flavorDimensions "default"

productFlavors {
    dev {
        dimension "default"
        applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        versionNameSuffix "_dev"
    }

    qa {
        dimension "default"
        applicationIdSuffix ".qa"
        versionNameSuffix "_qa"
    }

    demo1 {
        dimension "default"
        applicationIdSuffix ".demo"
        versionNameSuffix "_demo"
    }

    demo2 {
        dimension "default"
        applicationIdSuffix ".demo2"
        versionNameSuffix "_demo2"
    }

    prod {
        dimension "default"
    }
}
```

Then, I have lots of `dependencies`.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1'

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'

    // this is the dependency I would like to modify
    compile 'com.appsee:appsee-android:2.3.4'
}
```

my goal is to configure something where one of the dependency is only added if the `build variant` is one of the following: `demo2Debug`, `demo2Release`, `prodDebug` and `prodRelease`

I've looked at many answers (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36828415/3866010) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29661804/3866010)) and they do one build variant at a time. Is there any way to say:

**include this library is the build variant is this, this, this or this?**

**EDIT:**

Another way to achieve this would be to exclude a dependency from one specific build variant.

**Is there any way for me to say include this dependency for all build variants except for this?**

Comment: What you mean by this 'they do one build variant at a time' ? What you want to do exactly?

Comment: @Krish all examples I saw do the following: `demo2DebugCompile 'com.appsee:appsee-android:2.3.4'` then `demo2ReleaseCompile ...`, then `prodDebugCompile ...` and finally, `prodReleasCompile ...`. If I have do do this for 3 or 4 dependencies, it's just messy. Is there an easier way?