# Could not find method flavor1ReleaseImplementation()

Tags: android, gradle

Why can't I use it like this?

```
dependencies{
    flavor1ReleaseImplementation(name: "XXXA", ext: "aar")
    flavor2ReleaseImplementation(name: "XXXB", ext: "aar")
}
```

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method flavor1ReleaseImplementation() for arguments [{name=XXXA, ext=aar}] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

My Gradle Version

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'
...
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

[Solved, see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28137853/gradle-dependency-based-on-both-build-type-and-flavor)

```
android{
    productFlavors {
        flavor1{}
    }
}

configurations {
    flavor1DebugImplementation
    flavor1DebugImplementation
}
```