# Change dependency through a task in gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've build a lib, that in order to compile the application needs to set the specific flavor and release/debug type. 
However I'm trying to do this using a systemProperty when assembling the gradle via command.

To do that I'm doing something like this:

```
gradlew init assembleRelease -D P="flavor1"
```

On the build.gradle of the application I created a task to consume this "P" system property like:

```
task init(type: JavaExec){
        systemProperty "Production", System.getProperty("P")   //this variable comes from command variable
        rootProject.ext.set("Production", systemProperties["Production"]);
}
```

Despite all this the following code runs always before the init task:

```
dependencies{
   if(rootProject.ext.Production == "flavor1"){
      releaseCompile "compile with flavor1"
   }else{
      releaseCompile "compile with flavor2"
   }
}
```

Is there any way to change dependencies on the task init, in order to create an apk based on flavor set by a system property on a command line?

**Note**: I have an application, which add a dependency of a lib, which has many flavors, and what I want to change on the fly via the command line is the dependency to add on the application of this lib.

Comment: Is this an android library? you should be able to do assemble<Flavour>Release. Why the system properties?

Comment: This is an application which has an android lib which has many flavors. System property is for a custom and faster way to produce the APK based in an android lib flavor, only using a command flag. Instead of changing the defaultPublishConfig from the android lib or the dependency itself.

Comment: What is the problem or slowdown when using the following approach ? -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860659/multi-flavor-app-based-on-multi-flavor-library-in-android-gradle

Comment: I think i see your point, in creating a configuration on application and then defining flavors to corresponde the ones on android lib, that might work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what you do is just gambling. You do both, the setting of `rootProject.ext.Production` and the consuming of `rootProject.ext.Production` in the configuration phase. But I don't think there is some guarantee which is executed first the way you declared it. Besides that, using a `JavaExec` tasks configuration phase code to set some ext properties on the project is total non-sense anyway.

Instead of

```
task init(type: JavaExec){
    systemProperty "Production", System.getProperty("P")   //this variable comes from command variable
    rootProject.ext.set("Production", systemProperties["Production"]);
}

dependencies{
   if(rootProject.ext.Production == "flavor1"){
      releaseCompile "compile with flavor1"
   }else{
      releaseCompile "compile with flavor2"
   }
}
```

simply write

```
dependencies{
   if(System.properties.P == 'flavor1'){
      releaseCompile 'compile with flavor1'
   }else{
      releaseCompile 'compile with flavor2'
   }
}
```

or if you need it as variable on the rootProject because of subprojects needing the value in their build file

```
rootProject.ext.Production = System.properties.P;

dependencies{
   if(rootProject.Production == 'flavor1'){
      releaseCompile 'compile with flavor1'
   }else{
      releaseCompile 'compile with flavor2'
   }
}
```

If you just need it in the same build file multiple times, a local variable would also do, no need for a project ext-property

```
def production = System.properties.P;

dependencies{
   if(production == 'flavor1'){
      releaseCompile 'compile with flavor1'
   }else{
      releaseCompile 'compile with flavor2'
   }
}
```

---

Besides that, I wouldn't use a system property, but a project property.
Just use

```
dependencies{
   if(production == 'flavor1'){
      releaseCompile 'compile with flavor1'
   }else{
      releaseCompile 'compile with flavor2'
   }
}
```

and call it with `gradlew assembleRelease -P production=flavor1`

Comment: I did not think you could just simply call the system.property on the dependency. Additionally I liked the second approach too in order to use it on subprojects. Thanks alot!

Comment: With the last approach you can use it on any project. Project properties are inherited.