# Android Studio 3.0 Flavor Dimension Issue

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, armv7

Upgraded to Studio Canary build. My previous project of Telegram Messenger is giving following error.

> Error:All flavors must now belong to a named flavor dimension. The flavor 'armv7' is not assigned to a flavor dimension. Learn more at https://d.android.com/r/tools/flavorDimensions-missing-error-message.html

What should I do? I have already seen that link but couldn't understand what to do. I have 3 build variants now, release,debug and foss.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multi flavor app based on multi flavor library in Android Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860659/multi-flavor-app-based-on-multi-flavor-library-in-android-gradle)

Answer (score 571, accepted):

If you don't really need the mechanism, just specify a random flavor dimension in your `build.gradle` or `build.gradle.kts`:

```
android { 
    ...
    flavorDimensions("default")
    ...
}
```

For more information, check the [migration guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#flavor_dimensions)

Comment: Thanks. I already had a dimension "versionCode", I used that.

Comment: flavorDimensions "versionCode"

    productFlavors {
        debug {
            dimension "default"
            versionName "1.0"
        }

        release {
            dimension "default"
            versionName "1.0"
        }

        foss {
            dimension "default"
            versionName "1.0"
        }
    }                             I got this error ..ProductFlavor names cannot collide with BuildType names. Could you please anyone help me. I got this error AS 3.0 beta version Canary with Kotlin.

Comment: What do I do if I haven't used flavors anywhere in my build.gradle? I have 2 buildTypes, debug and release.

Comment: You still get that error while not having any flavors defined? Maybe some library you include uses flavors but no has no flavorDimension?

Comment: If you only have one dimension, you do not need to specify it in each flavor. Just the first `flavorDimensions "default"` line above is all that's needed.

Comment: @GrahamBorland thanks for the hint, I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: maybe add, that the file is `app/build.gradle`

Comment: This is not solving my  issue. I am having same issue.

Answer (score 63):

After trying and reading carefully, I solved it myself.
Solution is to add the following line in build.gradle.

> flavorDimensions "versionCode"

```
android { 
       compileSdkVersion 24
       .....
       flavorDimensions "versionCode"
}
```

Comment: where in the gradle do you add this line? A little more context would be helpful

Comment: Inside build.gradle file, in android {  ...  }

Comment: android {
    compileSdkVersion 24....                                                                                                                 //add here                                                                                                      }

Comment: why **"versionCode"** and not anything else ? will it affect versionCode 
anyhow ?

Comment: @MBH I have that in my productFlavours. You just need any unique key to identify.

Answer (score 41):

**Here you can resolve this issue, you need to add flavorDimension with productFlavors's name and need to define dimension as well, see below example and for more information see here** https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html

```
flavorDimensions 'yourAppName' //here defined dimensions
productFlavors {
    production {
        dimension 'yourAppName' //you just need to add this line
        //here you no need to write applicationIdSuffix because by default it will point to your app package which is also available inside manifest.xml file.

    }

    staging {
        dimension 'yourAppName' //added here also
        applicationIdSuffix ".staging"//(.staging) will be added after your default package name.
        //or you can also use applicationId="your_package_name.staging" instead of applicationIdSuffix but remember if you are using applicationId then You have to mention full package name.
        //versionNameSuffix "-staging"

    }

    develop {
        dimension 'yourAppName' //add here too
        applicationIdSuffix ".develop"
        //versionNameSuffix "-develop"

    }
```

Answer (score 20):

If you want not to use dimensions you should use this line

```
android { 
compileSdkVersion 24

...
flavorDimensions "default"
...
}
```

but if you want ti use dimensions you should declare your dimension name first and then use this name after
THIS example is from the documentations:

```
android {
...
buildTypes {
debug {...}
release {...}
}

  // Specifies the flavor dimensions you want to use. The order in which you
  // list each dimension determines its priority, from highest to lowest,
  // when Gradle merges variant sources and configurations. You must assign
  // each product flavor you configure to one of the flavor dimensions.
  flavorDimensions "api", "mode"

  productFlavors {
    demo {
  // Assigns this product flavor to the "mode" flavor dimension.
  dimension "mode"
  ...
}

full {
  dimension "mode"
  ...
}

// Configurations in the "api" product flavors override those in "mode"
// flavors and the defaultConfig block. Gradle determines the priority
// between flavor dimensions based on the order in which they appear next
// to the flavorDimensions property above--the first dimension has a higher
// priority than the second, and so on.
minApi24 {
  dimension "api"
  minSdkVersion 24
  // To ensure the target device receives the version of the app with
  // the highest compatible API level, assign version codes in increasing
  // value with API level. To learn more about assigning version codes to
  // support app updates and uploading to Google Play, read Multiple APK Support
  versionCode 30000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
  versionNameSuffix "-minApi24"
  ...
}

minApi23 {
  dimension "api"
  minSdkVersion 23
  versionCode 20000  + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
  versionNameSuffix "-minApi23"
  ...
}

minApi21 {
  dimension "api"
  minSdkVersion 21
  versionCode 10000  + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
  versionNameSuffix "-minApi21"
  ...
    }
  }
}
...
```

Answer (score 11):

I have used flavorDimensions for my application in build.gradle (Module: app)

```
flavorDimensions "tier"

productFlavors {
    production {
        flavorDimensions "tier"
        //manifestPlaceholders = [appName: APP_NAME]
        //signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    staging {
        flavorDimensions "tier"
        //manifestPlaceholders = [appName: APP_NAME_STAGING]
        //applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
        //versionNameSuffix "-staging"
        //signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
```

[Check this link for more info](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html?utm_source=android-studio#variant_aware)

```
// Specifies two flavor dimensions.
flavorDimensions "tier", "minApi"

productFlavors {
     free {
            // Assigns this product flavor to the "tier" flavor dimension. Specifying
            // this property is optional if you are using only one dimension.
            dimension "tier"
            ...
     }

     paid {
            dimension "tier"
            ...
     }

     minApi23 {
            dimension "minApi"
            ...
     }

     minApi18 {
            dimension "minApi"
            ...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

in KotlinDSL you can use like this :

```
flavorDimensions ("PlaceApp")
productFlavors {
    create("tapsi") {
        setDimension("PlaceApp")
        buildConfigField("String", "API_BASE_URL", "https://xxx/x/x/")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have simple flavors (free/pro, demo/full etc.) then add to build.gradle file:

```
android {
...
flavorDimensions "version"
productFlavors {
        free{
            dimension "version"
            ...
            }
        pro{
            dimension "version"
            ...
            }
}
```

By dimensions you can create "flavors in flavors". [Read more](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants?utm_source=android-studio#product-flavors).

Answer (score 0):

This what worked for me for latest as well  :

```
android {
...
flavorDimensions += "version"
}
```