# version code not found in android studio canary -2

Tags: android, version, manifest

> when instant run apply i am getting following in android studio 3.0 canary-2

```
Error:E:\PublicServer_Share\Extra\app\build\intermediates\instant-run
support\debug\slice_2\AndroidManifest.xml:2 attribute 'android:versionCode' 
not found
Error:failed processing manifest
Error:E:\PublicServer_Share\Extra\app\build\intermediates\instant-run-
support\debug\slice_9\AndroidManifest.xml:2 attribute 'android:versionCode' 
not found
Error:failed processing manifest
Error:Execution failed for task 
':app:transformDexWithInstantRunSlicesApkForDebug'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

Comment: As the same on Canary 3.

Answer (score 5):

Disable Instant Run. Inside `File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment`. This will allow you to run your app in the Canary version.

Comment: This works, but there's a better solution offered [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44105127/android-studio-3-0-flavor-dimension-issue/44105240#44105240).

Answer (score 1):

Run **Gradle->Clean** and try again