# Android studio 3.0 build variants does not match flavors

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-productflavors, android-studio-3.0

I'm trying to setup different build variants for Android Studio 3.0 and gradle plugin 3.0, but Android Studio doesn't create build variant for each my flavor. Gradle build is successfull but I don't know how to make productionapiRealese and germanyapiRelease build variants. How can I make it?

My flavors:

```
flavorDimensions "pr", "ger"
productFlavors {
    productionapi {

        provider "pk"
        dimension "pr"

    }
    germanyapi {
        provider "sd"
        dimension "ger"
    }
}
```

And my build variants:

[image]

Comment: Obviously because your flavors has different dimensions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio 3.0 Flavor Dimension Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44105127/android-studio-3-0-flavor-dimension-issue)

Comment: No, it is not.. He doesn't get any error.  If I understand his properly he wants to get productionapiDebug, germanapiDebug, and so on....

Comment: Selvin, so I need the same dimension for different variants?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all read this [article](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html?hl=en-419) in detail.

As far as I understand you are mixing flavors using the information you can find in this section "Combine multiple product flavors with flavor dimensions".

Just remove this:

```
flavorDimensions "pr", "ger"
```

and this from each flavor:

```
dimension "ger"
dimension "pr"
```

Just focus on the first part of the section "Configure Product Flavors":

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {...}
    buildTypes {...}
    flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
        productionapi {
            applicationIdSuffix ".prod"
            versionNameSuffix "-prod"
        }
        germanyapi {
            applicationIdSuffix ".german"
            versionNameSuffix "-german"
        }
    }
}
```

Doing that you will get a build variant for each flavor

Comment: Yes, you are right. But, also you need to add flavorDimensions "default" to build it successfully. If don't - it won't compile

Comment: @WorieN : I have the same issue, how do you fix the issue finally? Can you post the gradle script that fixed your issue?

Comment: @Mouss the gradle script is in my answer but as he said, you need to add flavorDimensions "default" also!

Comment: @LeandroOcampo : would it be possible please to add it directly to your post? When we are on stackoverflow, we often look only at post and not messages under the post... Thanx a lot :)

Comment: @LeandroOcampo : thanx a lot!