# Gradle can't see product flavors. How can I add them?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

When I try to add a flavor to my project, Gradle simply don't want to sync and even if I sync it I can't see the flavor in Build Variats. What can cause this problem? The project has a few modules, I need to add flavors to the app. My file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.24.4'
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


def keystorePropertiesFile = "${rootDir}${File.separator}keystore.properties" as File

keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

android {

    dexOptions {
           javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 9999
        versionName "17.2 (9999)"
    }

    productFlavors {
        testFlavor {
            applicationId "com.volodymyr.mobiletest"
        }
    }

    def keystoreFilePath = "${System.properties['user.home']}${File.separator}${keystoreProperties['storeFile']}"
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreFilePath)
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {

        }
        debug {

        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'//, 'x86', 'x86_64'
            universalApk true
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        lintConfig file("lint.xml")

        check "WrongConstant"
        abortOnError true
    }
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if(task.name.equals("assembleDebug")){
        task.dependsOn(lint)
    }
}
dependencies {
}
```

I deleted some info from here, like dependencies, id and so on just to show a structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in that that this gradle file is using only for CI. To change gradle config I needed to improve build file at settings.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

> Error:(15, 0) ProductFlavor names cannot start with 'test'

You should use another flavor name

Comment: ^^ cannot start with 'test' not mean equal `test`. your flavor name now is `testFlavor` (it start with test). you should change it to demoFlavor or abcFlavor, ... not test...

Comment: I still can't see "Sourse set" if I add some resource. Gradle still don't want to sync and I don't see flavors at Build Types

Comment: what is your android studio version? does gradle display any error? try restart android studio.

Comment: 3.0. No errors, may it be caused by gradle version?

Comment: which is  your build gradle?

Comment: 2.3.3 because of project. I also tried 3.0.0 -- the same. But if I create small test app I can do it without problems. In build types I see just release and debug, while I expect flavors

Comment: im using android studio 3 with gradle:3.0.0 and flavor work ok :D. note that you need to add flavorDimensions when use use AS 3.0 https://stackoverflow.com/a/44105198/5381331

Comment: It works well for me too, but exactly at that project it doesn't work

Comment: I have no more idea because your AS don't show any error log. I suggest that you should try remove each property in your gradle and sync project step by step and figure out which thing make your flavor not work