# Ionic android build error : "All flavors must now belong to a named flavor dimension"

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle

I've started a new project on my computer but I'm not able anymore to build for android

When I run

```
ionic cordova platform run android
```

I get this error :

```
All flavors must now belong to a named flavor dimension.
```

Comment: Do you have any code reference for this?

Comment: Definitely the weirdest error I have ever seen :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The "flavours" error will occur if you have the `cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview` plugin installed in your project and you try to build with Gradle v4.

However, if you want to upgrade to `cordova-android@6.4.0` (e.g. to open your Cordova Android platform project in Android Studio 3 to debug native plugin code), you'll need to upgrade to Gradle v4.
Hence `cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview` is currently incompatible with `cordova-android@6.4.0`.

As a manual workaround for the "flavours" error, you can insert a default flavour in the `platforms/android/build.gradle` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44105198/777265)):

```
android { 
    ...
    flavorDimensions "default"
    ...
}
```

**Update**

If you want to build with Gradle v4/`cordova-android@6.4+` and `cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview`, update to Gradle v4 then install `cordova-android` off the master branch, since [this PR](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/pull/417) to resolve the "flavours" error with multiple APK builds has now been merged:

```
cordova platform rm android 
  && cordova platform add https://github.com/apache/cordova-android
```

Comment: > Hence cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview is currently incompatible with cordova-android@6.4.0

This is only true if you are building separate apks for the two versions. If you set `xwalkMultipleApk` to `false` - e.g. `    <preference name="xwalkMultipleApk" value="false" />` in `config.xml`, you can use gradle 4 + cordova-android@6.4.

    $ gradle -v

    ---------------------
    Gradle 4.4.1
    ---------------------

    $ cordova platform ls
    Installed platforms:
      android 6.4.0
      ios 4.5.4

Comment: I have checked that PR you told, but this code are not on release 6.4.0 nor 7.0.0

Comment: Now i am getting this error after adding the flavorDimention: default

`A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Flavor 'armv7' has no flavor dimension.`

Comment: @SriKrishna anything you found for `Flavor 'armv7' has no flavor dimension.` ?

Answer (score 2):

I get the same error and i have created a script to solve it.

As there was said in the answer, the problem is: gradle 4 wants flavorDimensions on gradle.build.

If you check here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/#extending-buildgradle

We can create a file named gradle-extra.build with will be included on gradle.build, we just need to create a script to paste this file on /platform/android/.

So i created this file build-extras.gradle in my project root

```
android { 
    flavorDimensions "default"
}
```

and the script on ./hooks/after_platform_add/copy_build-extras.gradle.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

if(fs.existsSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../platforms/android'))) {
  fs.createReadStream(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../build-extras.gradle')).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../platforms/android/build-extras.gradle')));
}
```

You can check about hooks here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/hooks/index.html

every script under /hooks/after_platform_add will be executed after ionic platform add ***

With this, we don't need to downgrade gradle nor change cordova-android version.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. :)

Gradle version was the problem. I had to downgrade from 4.X to 3.5.1, which workds great!

Check you gradle version by doing

```
gradle -v
```

If if's > 4.x, downgrade it!

Comment: Not really a solution. Adding flavorDimensions "default" to build.gradle fix the problem.

Comment: Yeah but you're modifying unversionned files. Doesn't seem like a good solution to me.

Comment: platforms/android/build.gradle is in the versioning system

Comment: I think that by default, node_modules, platforms and plugins folders are not versioned by the ionic team ;)

Comment: "platforms" should contain also your Java or ObjC code, or where should it be ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue should be solved in this PR: https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview/pull/255