# Implementation project Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android-studio-3.0

android studio multiple modules project
Where can the problem be?
Error Messages Print Screen - **[image: Enter image description here.]**

***project build.gradle***

```
    buildscript { repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

***app build.gradle***

...

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation project(':t2')

}
```

***Setting gradle***

```
include ':app', ':t2'
```

Comment: Your problem can be solved with this[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47768140/7890329) Thanks to @Duy Phan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been fixed with the new versions of Gradle(v3.3.0) and AndroidStudio(v3.3).