# Cannot resolve symbol v7 in importing appcompatactivity

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-appcompat, appcompatactivity

I'm new to Android Studio and it was working just fine and I made few apps and they worked pretty well, and then I downloaded a project from GitHub and tried to import it, the project didn't work but now every time I make new project this error happens:(I can't upload pictures)

Import `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity`;
The 'v7' is colored in red and it says it can't resolve symbol v7

In the messages it giving me this:

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1)

I tried the following:

1. invalidate caches and restart
2. compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0' in the
   dependencies in the build.gradle
3. clean project and sync project with Gradle files

But nothing worked.

I have Android studio 3.0.1
Android emulator 27.1.12
Android SDK platform tools 27.0.1
Android SDK tools 26.1.1

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949622/android-studio-3-0-unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdexoptions-compileclas

Comment: If you try with support library version 25, is it working? If not, try removing `.gradle` in your project. Are you using Android Studio 3.1.1?

Comment: It didn't work , everything was working just fine but after I imported this project from GitHub this error occurred

Comment: No I use version 3.0.1

Comment: Sorry I'm new to android studio , how can I try support library version 25?

Comment: There's a message in "Gradle bulid" tab : > no cached version of com.android.support .appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1 available for offline mode

Comment: I solved by changing the implementation from 26.0.0-beta1 to 26.1.0 and com.android.support.test:runner:0.5 to 1.0.1 and com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2 to 3.0.1  but do I need to do this to every new project?

Comment: This probably a bug. You should try update your Android Studio to version 3.1.1. It's pretty stable.

Answer (score 2):

To use support libraries starting from version 26.0.0 you need to add Google's Maven repository to your project's build.gradle file as described here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven {
                url "https://maven.google.com"
            }
        }
    }
```

For Android Studio 3.0.0 and above:

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            google()
        }
    }
```