# some error on dependencies after updating Android Studio to 3.1.3

Tags: android, gradle, build, dependencies, android-studio-3.1

Hi I have some error on build... 
I am new In android studio 
I dont have problem until I update my android studio to 3.1.3...
Now I sow the errors on gradle build about Unable to resolve dependency for ...

Its My build.gradle(Module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.shoaib.newsletters"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    compile 'com.tomerrosenfeld.customanalogclockview:custom-analog-clock-view:1.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

and My build.gradle(Project:)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And there is errors

```
Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
Open File
Show Details
```

Please tell me how to solve these Problem...

Comment: See this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949622/android-studio-3-0-unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdexoptions-compileclas?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android studio 3.0: Unable to resolve dependency for :app@dexOptions/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :animators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949622/android-studio-3-0-unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdexoptions-compileclas)

Answer (score 1):

As you are using appcompact-v7:26.1.0

your constraint layout version must be

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

and test should be

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
```

Kindly update if this helps you