# Adding dependency on app with product flavors

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-app-bundle

I'm trying out the Android's latest app packaging and delivery model, [App Bundles](https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle/).

I've created a dynamic feature module and defined a dependency on the main app.

`implementation(':app')`

Now my `app` module has different `productFlavors`.

```
productFlavors {
  free {
    ...
  }

  pro {
    ...
  }
}
```

My dynamic feature does not require any product flavors. But I now get the following error on gradle sync -

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':dynamic_feature@debug/compileClasspath': 
Could not resolve project :app.
```

I can fix this by defining the same `productFlavors` in my dynamic feature module, but is it absolutely necessary?

I am generalizing a case where I have many different submodules and `productFlavors` and defining `productFlavors` in each module feels redundant.

Comment: Have you checked this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949622/android-studio-3-0-unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdexoptions-compileclas)?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you'll have to declare a `missingDimensionStrategy` for the dynamic feature module which doesn't have the flavor.

In your `com.android.dynamic-feature` module you'd add something like this

```
android {
// other things
    defaultConfig {
        // other things
        missingDimensionStrategy 'pro' // or whichever dimension you want to use
    }
}
```

You can find more about this and why this is necessary in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies).