# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':Could not resolve project :PGSDKVR4.AggrePay-android

Tags: android, plugins, runtime-error

This is my gradle file :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "apps.com.athulyacustomer"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(":PGSDKVR4")
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    implementation 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.nipun-birla:BoxLoaderView:0.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```

Getting the below mentioned error after syncing the gradle with the project folder.

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :PGSDKVR4.

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :PGSDKVR4.

Have added the plugin according to the documentation and sample app present on the below mentioned links.

https://github.com/paymentgatewayintegration/sampleapp

Please do let me know how can i can find a solution to this error.
Awaiting for your replies.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949622/android-studio-3-0-unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdexoptions-compileclas/52163856
this link will help you check it once

Comment: @Anand i tried all the solutions but getting the same error ...can you please suggest anything different/more.

Answer (score 0):

update dependencies in your projects build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
    }
```

Comment: the current gradle version that i am using is : classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1' and i also tried changing but still getting the same error