# When I set Custom buildTypes , I got some error.Who could Help me?

Tags: android, gradle

First, this is a demo. In the process of learning how to use gradle，I wanna add the custom buildTypes for apk,this is my application module app-> build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-aspectjx'
apply plugin: 'patcher'
apply plugin: 'kotlintest'
apply plugin: 'javaTest'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.person.ermao.aoptest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            debuggable true
        }
        staging {
            initWith debug
            manifestPlaceholders = [hostName:"internal.example.com"]
            applicationIdSuffix ".debugStaging"
        }
    }
//    splits {
//        // Settings to build multiple APKs based on screen density.
//        density {
//
//            // Enable or disable building multiple APKs.
//            enable true
//
//            // Exclude these densities when building multiple APKs.
//            exclude "ldpi", "tvdpi", "xxxhdpi", "400dpi", "560dpi"
//        }
//    }
    patcher {
        sourceApk "com.person.ermao"
        ignoreWarning true
        useSign true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
aspectjx {

//排除所有package路径中包含`android.support`的class文件及库（jar文件）

    exclude 'android.support'

}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation('io.mockk:mockk-android:1.9.3') { exclude module: 'objenesis' }
    androidTestImplementation 'org.objenesis:objenesis:2.6'
    implementation project(':aop')
}
```

i got some error:

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@staging/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :aop.
>   Open File
>   Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@stagingUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :aop.
>   Open File
>   Show Details

Comment: please have a look into below links: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949622/android-studio-3-0-unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdexoptions-compileclas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949622/android-studio-3-0-unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdexoptions-compileclas) and [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949622/android-studio-3-0-unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdexoptions-compileclas/47101413](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949622/android-studio-3-0-unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdexoptions-compileclas/47101413)

Answer (score 0):

try to add another field to each variant:
matchingFallbacks = ['Put Hear The Variant Name'] // for projects who doesn't have this variant defined