# How to fix "could not resolve project ..." in react-native android app?

Tags: android, react-native

Having an issue in a fresh react-native project, v0.63.2. `npm install`'d `react-native-splash-screen`, did not run `react-native link <...>`. Manullay linked the package by:

- editing settings.gradle ->

  `include ':react-native-splash-screen' project(':react-native-splash-screen').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-splash-screen')`
- added dependency to app/build.gradle ->

`dependencies { ... implementation project(':react-native-splash-screen') }`

- added package to MainApplication.java:

`import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreenReactPackage;`

```
        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          packages.add(new SplashScreenReactPackage());
          return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }
      };
```

However I noticed theres no `react-native-splash-screen` module in the Android directory view:

[image]

I then tried running `react-native link react-native-splash-screen` which did not affect the change I need

The build error:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': 
Could not resolve project :react-native-splash-screen.
Affected Modules: app
```

how to fix? I tried most of the suggestions here: [Android studio 3.0: Unable to resolve dependency for :app@dexOptions/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :animators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949622/android-studio-3-0-unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdexoptions-compileclas) to no avail