# Unable to build after installing react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, google-maps

I'm trying to implement google maps in my android app using React Native
I did all the following which I was supposed to do.
and I am getting this error in android studios
enter image description here

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you can show your configuration.
If your react-native version is below .59 you need to manually link
[https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md#build-configuration-on-android]

Comment: yes i did that. but still it is not working

Comment: Looks like there are issues on the dependencies. Have you tried the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949622/ ?