# Android Studio can not add library project in build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, tensorflow, gradle

I want to integrate the [tensorflow lite example](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/image_classification/android) in my project. What I already did:

- Renaming `app` to `lib_tensorFlow` (you can not have 2 'app's)
- Make the `lib_tensorFlow` Module to a library by changing to `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`
- deleting the `applicationId`
- Importing the Project as Gradle Module
- Adding `implementation project(":lib_tensorFlow")` to my apps dependencies
- Searching for a offline mode in Gradle settings (There is no such option)
- Invalidate Cache & restart
- Googling

The Error I get when gradle builds the project:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@regularDebugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :lib_tensorFlow.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@regularDebugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :lib_tensorFlow.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@regularDebug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :lib_tensorFlow.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

Please don't mark this as duplicate. I have searched in every possible Thread.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The example already have 2 module build . have you created a new module ? or you are just using the same modules from example ?

Comment: Is the library included in your `settings.gradle` file?
`include ':app', ':lib_tensorFlow'`

Comment: 1- I am using the same modules as in the example
2- Yes it is included

Comment: if u r using same module i do not see a module named `lib_tensorFlow` in the example . There r two modules named `lib_support` and `lib_task_api`. [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/image_classification/android/app/build.gradle).

Comment: I renamed it to lib_tensorflow because you can't have two modules with the name "app" as said above

Comment: this might be a similar issue to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949622/android-studio-3-0-unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdexoptions-compileclas 
or maybe the solutions there would just help too