# Include library with flavor android

Tags: android, gradle

My app gradle file before:

`compile project(path: ':zblelib')`

But when i add flavors into the lib my import don't work

my flavors:

```
flavorDimensions "dim"
    productFlavors {
        nocustomer {
            versionNameSuffix "-nocustomer"
            dimension = "dim"
        }
        customer001 {
            versionNameSuffix "-customer001"
            dimension = "dim"
        }
    }
```

how can i import my new library with choice of flavor?

edit: my build.gradle

**library**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }

    flavorDimensions "dim"
    productFlavors {
        nocustomer {
            versionNameSuffix "-nocustomer"
            dimension = "dim"
        }
        customer001 {
            versionNameSuffix "-customer001"
            dimension = "dim"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    compile project(':criptolib-debug')
}
```

**app**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultPublishConfig "nocustomerRelease"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.axesstmc.bleappphone"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 91
        versionName "8.2"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            //proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    ? ?
}
```

Comment: Can you put the `build.gradle` files for your app and your library ?

Comment: @xiaomi i will edit my answer

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem the app has is that it doesn't know which library's flavor to use.

The keyword `matchingFallbacks` will tell the app which library's flavor you want to select. But this keyword has to be use with a Flavor.

We have to add a flavor (+ dimension) on your app build.gradle:

```
android {
    ...
    //flavorDimensions is mandatory with flavors. Use the same name on your 2 files to avoid other conflicts.
    flavorDimensions "dim"
    productFlavors {
        nocustomer{
            dimension "dim"

            // App and library's flavor have the same name.
            // MatchingFallbacks can be omitted
            matchingFallbacks = ["nocustomer"]
        }
        customerNb{
            dimension "dim"

            // Here the app and library's flavor are different
            // Matching fallbacks will select the library's flavor 'customer001'
            matchingFallbacks = ["customer001"]
        }
    }
    ...
}
dependencies {
    implementation project(':zblelib')
}
```

In this way, when you select the app's flavor `nocustomer`, the library's flavor will select automatically `nocustomer`, and when you select the app's flavor `customerNb`, the library's flavor will select automatically `customer001`

**PS**

I am using `implementation` instead of `compile`, because compile is deprecated ([see here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html?#new_configurations))

Comment: What if we have multiple Library, each having multiple Flavors?! For correct solution see: stackoverflow.com/[**Multi Flavor App with multi Flavor Library?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24860659/8740349)

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `missingDimensionStrategy`
 in your app's `build.gradle` file where it matches the missing flavors from your library. Check [migration docs for Gradle 3.0.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#resolve_matching_errors) how to implement it.

For your particular problem where your library includes product flavors that the app doesn't check section `A library dependency includes a flavor dimension that your app does not.` from the table.

EDIT:
Define flavors in your app's `build.gradle` file and then use `matchingFallbacks` to specify exactly which flavor you are to match from the libraries.

```
productFlavors {
    paid {
        dimension 'tier'
        matchingFallbacks = ['customer001', 'nocustomer']
    }
    free {
        dimension 'tier'
        matchingFallbacks = ['nocustomer', 'customer001']
    }
}
```

Comment: How to specify which flavour is used by my app? I want (i would :D) use my library flavour "nocustomer" for example.

Comment: First, you should define product flavors in your app's `build.gradle` file and then use `matchingFallbacks `. Check edit for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would should another way to implementation this:

First add a flavor and dimension to your app `build.gradle` which gradle id is `com.android.application`,like below:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    resourcePrefix "app_"
    flavorDimensions "env"
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension "env"
        }
        pre{
            dimension "env"
        }
        prod {
            dimension "env"
        }
    }
}
```

And then add the below code snippt to your library module

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
}

android {
    resourcePrefix "base_"

    flavorDimensions "env"
    productFlavors {
        register("dev")
        register("pre")
        register("prod")
    }
}
```

[image]