# Import a specific flavour from a library module

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I create a library module with two flavors. Each flavor implements a `FlavourActivity.java` in a different way. In my app I'm what to import my library module as a dependency, **but I want to specify which flavor I'm going to import**.

My problem is that I'm able to add the dependency in my app gradle file, but I cannot access the `FlavourActivity.java`. Somehow my app does not have access to it, although it has imported the library.

---

### Structure

My structure is the following:

```
app/
├── src/
│   ├── Activity.java

Library/
├── lottieYes/
│   ├── FlavourActivity.java
├── lottieNo/
│   ├── FlavourActivity.java
```

Android Plugin Version: 3.4.0
Gradle Version: 5.1.0

---

#### Recources

My app gradle file is the following:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.asousa.testing.moduleflavour"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    implementation project(path: ':mylibrary', configuration: 'lottieYes')
}
```

My library gradle file is the following:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    publishNonDefault true

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    flavorDimensions "lottie"

    productFlavors {
        lottieYes {
            dimension "lottie"
        }

        lottieNo {
            dimension "lottie"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    lottieYes
    lottieNo
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    lottieYesImplementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.6'
}
```

---

I already read the following articles:

- [Product Flavors for Android Library](https://android.jlelse.eu/product-flavors-for-android-library-d3b2d240fca2)
- [Support Flavors and BuildTypes across library modules](https://medium.com/@elye.project/support-flavors-and-buildtypes-across-library-modules-31acf9c6d806)

I also checked the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860659/multi-flavor-app-based-on-multi-flavor-library-in-android-gradle), but it not solve my issue since with the latest gradle version it does not work.

But none of them helped me. Does someone had a similar issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi flavor app based on multi flavor library in Android Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860659/multi-flavor-app-based-on-multi-flavor-library-in-android-gradle)

Comment: Already read that post, not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the future record, I found a solution to my problem by declaring the `java.srcDirs` and `res.srcDirs` according to the feature state.

---

I declare a gradle external property declaring if the feature is enabled or not.

```
project.ext {
  hasLottie = true
}
```

More info on this [blog post](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html)

---

And on my library gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    publishNonDefault true

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            if (hasLottieSupport.toBoolean()) {
                java.srcDirs += 'lottieYes/java'

            } else {
                java.srcDirs += 'lottieNo/java'
                res.srcDirs += 'lottieNo/res'
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

    if (hasLottieSupport.toBoolean()) {
        implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.6'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
   ......
   flavorDimensions "lottie"

   productFlavors {
     lottieYes {
        dimension "lottie"
     }

     lottieNo {
        dimension "lottie"
     }
   }
}

dependencies {
   ......
   lottieNoimplementation project(path: ':mylibraryX')
   lottieYesimplementation project(path: ':mylibraryY')

}
```