# Use gradle module as a dependency with specific flavor

Tags: android, gradle, module, android-gradle-plugin

I have a library module called `library` that has two flavors `flavor1` and `flavor2`. Then I have two application modules, lets call them `app1` and `app2` that will use this library module and each one will use it with specific flavor .. eg. `app1` will always use `library` with `flavor1` flavor. How should I configure gradle dependencies to make it do what I want to? If I try just `implementation project(':library')` in `app1` `build.gradle` it obviously does not work because it doesn't know which flavor to choose .. so I’ve tried something like `implementation project(path: ':library', configuration: 'flavor1Release')` but  that does not work too, it prints a lot of errors like

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app1@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :library.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app1

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app1@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :library.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app1

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app1@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :library.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app1

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app1@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :library.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app1

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app1@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :library.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app1
```

I've seen some questions here on SO like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860659/multi-flavor-app-based-on-multi-flavor-library-in-android-gradle) that says to copy flavors from library module to main app module, but it does not make sense to me, `app1` doesn't know anything about `flavor2` and I don't want to introduce it there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi flavor app based on multi flavor library in Android Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860659/multi-flavor-app-based-on-multi-flavor-library-in-android-gradle)

Comment: @JeelVankhede that is the solution with copying the flavors to all modules which does not make sense in my case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should define `missingDimensionStrategy` for both `app1` and `app2`.

For example:

```
// app1/build.gradle

 defaultConfig {
    missingDimensionStrategy 'library', 'flavor1'
}

// app2/build.gradle

 defaultConfig {
    missingDimensionStrategy 'library', 'flavor2'
}
```

Comment: You are right! Just one small change, 'library' in your example should specify flavor dimension :)