# No classes from main sources from multi flavor library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-productflavors, android-flavors

I have a library project with 2 flavors

```html
configurations {
    // Initializes placeholder configurations that the Android plugin can use when targeting
    // the corresponding variant of the app.
    internalDebug {}
    internalRelease {}
    externalDebug {}
    externalRelease {}
}

flavorDimensions("outerInner")
productFlavors {
    internal{dimension "outerInner"}
    external{dimension "outerInner"}
}
```

No custom sourceSets defined in build.gradle

For one of the flavor I have custom layouts inside:

[image]

All other sources should be from `main`.

When I include this libaryr to app:

`implementation project(path: ':sdk', configuration: 'internalDebug')`

There no classes of the `sdk` library at all and all imports marks as red.

The question is why there is no sources from `main`'s library folders in app?

Comment: Do you have *product flavors* in **main app module**?

Comment: @JeelVankhede no, I guess it should **not** be a problem since I explicitly set configuration I want to use.

Comment: I had in my case *(Multi flavor library -> multi flavor app with different names of product flavors)*, try this in library gradle `publishNonDefault true` in `android {}` block.

Comment: @JeelVankhede nope, doesn't help... could you share you build.gradle for library and main app?

Comment: Sorry @dilix, I can not share Gradle files right now because it's no longer accessible by me, but here is the solution that I referred at that time which was helpful for me : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36828415/10271334. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the solution as defining `missingDimensionStrategy` in app's `build.gradle`.

```html
// Specifies a sorted list of flavors that the plugin should try to use from
// a given dimension. The following tells the plugin that, when encountering
// a dependency that includes a "minApi" dimension, it should select the
// "minApi18" flavor. You can include additional flavor names to provide a
// sorted list of fallbacks for the dimension.
missingDimensionStrategy 'outerInner', 'internal'
```

It means that if during the build gradle will found a dependency that have the `flavorDimension` `outerInner` it should use `internal` for that.

After this is applied I could simply include

`implementation project(path: ':sdk')`

For each app's buildType it will use appropriate `debug` or `relese` SDK build and fallback to `internal` implementation.

`External` implementation is delivered to maven with `artifact bundleExternalDebugAar` setting.

Comment: Thanks. This is useful for adding a dependency on a project without defining flavors as in the library `missingDimensionStrategy 'your_dimension', 'your_default_flavor'`.